# FileZilla Error: Could not connect to server

Tags: hosting, cpanel, filezilla

So I'm hosting a website on GoDaddy and using cPanel I have to upload only one file at a time. When I try FileZilla it just says could not connect. I'm using port 21.

Heres the log:

```
Status: Connecting to 166.62.28.144:21...

Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...

Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------

Response:   220-You are user number 6 of 500 allowed.

Response:   220-Local time is now 04:59. Server port: 21.

Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login

Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.

Command:    AUTH TLS

Error:  Could not connect to server

Status: Waiting to retry...

Status: Connecting to 166.62.28.144:21...

Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...

Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------

Response:   220-You are user number 7 of 500 allowed.

Response:   220-Local time is now 05:00. Server port: 21.

Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login

Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.

Command:    AUTH TLS

Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Comment: Your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the secured FTP port 22 and then check

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Ther was a problem with my network. Something to do with DNS. I basically connected to another network (phone hotspot)->other IP and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but this will definitely help.

1. Login to your cpanel.
2. Select the ftp account [Ftp account on cpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV89A.png)
3. Then scroll down to the list of your ftp account and click configure ftp [(image)configure ftp button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmcQW.png)
4. Download the filezilla configuration for your server [(image)filezilla configuration for your server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta7hN.png)
5. Afterwards go back to your filezilla software and import the downloaded file.

---

**TO IMPORT**:

1. Go to your filezilla software page and click file menu [(image)file menu click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRhAz.png)
2. From the menu list click import file.
3. Select the file and import then try connecting.